# The number of sets $X$, such that $X\subseteq A$ and $X \subsetneq B$, where $A=${$a,b,c,d,e$}, $B=${$c,d$}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> The number of sets $X$, such that $X\subseteq A$ and $X \subsetneq B$, where $A=${$a,b,c,d,e$}, $B=${$c,d$}
> (1)26
> (2)27
> (3)28
> (4)29

**Answer: (3)**

well hard to say but i don't know what is actually asked in the question. I don't understand the meaning of the line: *The number of sets $X$*

Comment: collect "all subsets of $A$ such that contain one of the elements $a,b,$ or $e$" . now *Count* them. it is **The number**

Comment: Here is one such set $X$ which is a subset of $A$ but not a subset of $B$: $\{a,c\}$.  How many are there in total?

Comment: They want to know how many subsets in $X$ such that the conditons of the question are met.

Comment: When you read the statement "The number of sets $X$ satisfying *blah* and *blah blah*", it means that they want you to find the number of sets that satisfy *blah* and *blah blah*.  They just so happen to call the arbitrary set $X$, then show you what the set must satisfy using the symbol $X$.  $X$ just represents an arbitrary set.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ has to contain $a, b$ or $e$.

We can find the number of ways we can form $X$ that has those elements.

Let's say we want to put $a$ in $X$. Then for each other element in $\{b,c,d,e \}$, we have two choices, to include it, or not to include it. Hence, we have $2^4$ sets for $X$ to include $a$. The same can be said about including $b$ and $e$.

But, this way, we counted things twice here. So we subtract the intersections.

There are $2^3$ ways to include both $a$ and $b$ (using the same method). This is the same for including $b,e$ and the same for including $e,a$.

But that means we subtracted too much. So we go back and add what we missed, which is having all $a,b,e$ together in $X$. The ways to do that is $2^2$.

hence the answer is $2^4 \cdot 3 - 2^3 \cdot 3 + 2^2 = 28$

In short, remember that the ways of having an element of $a, b$ or $e$ (call it $W(a \lor b \lor e)$) is $W(a) + W(b) + W(e) - W(a \land b) - W(b \land e) - W(a \land e) + W(a \land b \land e)$.

Answer (score 2):

**I must not be understanding the question at all.  My answer is so simple, it must be wrong:**

> (Is it possible you meant $\not \subseteq$ when you wrote $\subsetneq$?  Do you know the difference between the two?)

We need that $X$ is a subset of $A$ *and* $X$ is a **proper subset** of $B$.  Since $B = \{c, d \}$, and we want $X$ to be a proper subset of $B$, then $X$ can take one of three forms: $\emptyset$, $\{c \}$, or $\{d \}$.

This is because the subsets of $B$ are $\emptyset$, $\{ c \}$, $\{ d \}$, and $\{c, d \}$.  The first three are the only proper subsets.  So the answer is the number 3, not any of the choices you gave.

Comment: no i dont know that

Comment: @anni The symbol $\subsetneq$ is one way to describe "proper subset" (i.e., a subset that isn't equal to the whole set).  So we could write $\{1 \} \subsetneq \{1, 2 \}$.  Meanwhile, $\not \subseteq$ means the set is *not* a subset of the other set, for example we can write $\{1, 5 \} \not \subset \{1, 2 \}$.  To get $\not \subseteq$, write \not \subseteq between dollar signs.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previuos answer, the number of these subsets is  $2^5-2^2=28$. Where  $2^5$is the number of subsets of A and  $2^2$ is the number of subsets of B.